# How do you return key-value pairs from a function where the key is the input and the value is the output?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looping a function over a list of values `inputs` that returns a list of values `outputs` like this:

```
outputs = []
for i in inputs[:]:
     outputs.append(str(function(i)))
```

How do I set up a dictionary that populates key value pairs of inputs and outputs like below?

```
input1, output1
input2, output2
```

Comment: Use a dictionary comprehension `{i: str(function(i)) for i in inputs}`

Comment: You aren't modify `inputs` in the loop, so there is no reason to create a new list to iterate over; `for i in inputs:` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just map your function over the input, then zip the result with the original input and pass *that* sequence of tuples to `dict`:

```
d = dict(zip(inputs, [str(function(i)) for i in inputs]))
```

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary comprehension can be used for this pretty easily.

```
def function(s):
    return s.replace('input', 'output')
inputs = ['input1', 'input2']
pairs = {i: str(function(i)) for i in inputs}
print(pairs)
```

Output

```
{'input1': 'output1', 'input2': 'output2'}
```